# How to use PostSharp.Community.Packer

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-assembly, postsharp, packer

I installed PostSharp.Community.Packer via Visual Studio 2019 Nuget Manager and restarted.
I tried adding [assembly: Packer] at the end of my code, but it does not read. I can't build because I think it doesn't recognize it

Comment: Could you please update your question and include the error message(s) you're getting?

Answer (score -1):

It's probably the PS0242    License error. No valid license key has been installed. To register a license key, see https://doc.postsharp.net/deploying-keys.